# Convert String Representation Of Array To Actual Array In Python

Tags: python

I am quite new to python , and am struggling to make this work.

I need to convert

```
["ladksa dlskdlsd slkd sldks lskds lskds","skkdsdl skdsl lskds lsdk sldk sdslkds"] - String Representation of Array To Actual Array Like this.

[0]-> "ladksa dlskdlsd slkd sldks lskds lskds"
[1]-> "skkdsdl skdsl lskds lsdk sldk sdslkds"
```

I have tried following things:

```
json.load(array) -> but it gave me parse array error
literal_eval(x)  -> read it somewhere (dont know why it doesn't work)
```

Error:

```
custom_classes = json.loads(element.custom_classes)
 File "C:\Users\Shri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init_
.py", line 357, in loads
   return _default_decoder.decode(s)
 File "C:\Users\Shri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder
py", line 337, in decode
   obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
 File "C:\Users\Shri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder
py", line 355, in raw_decode
   raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Also, I am using below js code to send data:

```
'custom_classes':'\''+JSON.stringify(finalized_classes)+'\'',
```

Data Is Stored as :
[Please check image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lhMy.png)

and

```
arr_element = array of Objects For Specific Class
```

which has a property

```
custom_classes -> which is stored as above image.
```

and i am doing:

```
for element in arr_element:
    string_obj = json.loads(str(element.custom_classes))
    //here it is error
```

Please help

Comment: What error do you get when you try `json.load()`? Or `literal_eval()`? You need to post your errors so we can help you.

Comment: Use `json.loads` instead of `json.load`

Comment: The last line of your error is missing

Answer (score 3):

```py
import json

s = '["ladksa dlskdlsd slkd sldks lskds lskds","skkdsdl skdsl lskds lsdk sldk sdslkds"]'

json.loads(s)

# gives ['ladksa dlskdlsd slkd sldks lskds lskds', 'skkdsdl skdsl lskds lsdk sldk sdslkds']
```

Comment: your codes does work. but i am still facing issue when i am retrieving it from model

Comment: Ok, please add to question what exactly is at `element.custom_classes`.

Comment: Hi, i have added info in question.

Comment: Thanks, I rather meant to print like for example `print('element.custom_classes')` and maybe `type(element.custom_classes)`.

Answer (score 0):

After you use `json.loads()`, you can use `str.split()` to turn the strings into arrays, and then append one of the arrays onto the other if you need to.

```py
foo = ['this is a sentence', 'this is a different sentence']

bar = foo[0].split(' ')
biz = foo[1].split(' ')

bar.append(biz)

print(bar)
```

Result: `['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'different', 'sentence']`